# Comparing predictors in a logistic regression with different degrees of freedom

Tags: regression, logistic, deviance

I have a logistic regression for which different predictors have different degrees of freedom (for example, a categorical variable with 10 categories and a continuous variable).

I would like to compare the different predictors in terms of their "predicting power". I computed and compared their corresponding deviance (using anova function in R). Is their a way to account for the  different degrees of freedom of each predictor? Should I divide the explained deviance by the number of degrees of freedom?

Answer (score 1):

There are two approaches that I like.  One is to use AIC (in R type `AIC(fit1); AIC(fit2)`) which is roughly described as a method to tell you which of the two models is more likely to cross-validate with better log-likelihood.  This penalizes the $\chi^2$ of a model by twice the number of degrees of freedom (parameters) needed to achieve the likelihood ratio $\chi^2$.  Secondly, I often use the Wald or likelihood ratio $\chi^2$ statistic for a variable minus the degrees of freedom for that test.  This is a "chance correction", as the expected value of the $\chi^{2}_{p}$ statistic is $p$ under the null hypothesis that the $p$ coefficients are all zero.  When you use the R `rms` package and run `plot(anova(fit))` you get $\chi^{2} - p$ by default, using Wald statistics.